# Angular - Add user (POST)

Tags: angular

I would like to add user to databse per Java Spring Backend. I use POST method in angular.
I have interface:

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  login: string;
  password: string;
 }
```

service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {User} from './interfaces/User';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public addUser(newUser: User): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/newuser', newUser);
  }

  public extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

}
```

and register component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';
import {User} from '../interfaces/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  addUser(emailText: string, passwordText: string) {

    const newUser: User = ({
      id: null,
      login: emailText,
      password: passwordText
    });

    this.userService.addUser(newUser);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(newUser));
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly is not working. What is the issue in my POST method? The GET users working good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you check your network panel of your browser, do you see the `POST` request, if yes what the request params look like, what is the status code returned ? What is the value of your console.log in `addUser` method ?

Comment: You don't `.subscribe` to the observable: https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution 1:**  Using `RequestOptions` to inform the server that the request content is of type JSON. You already have an unused `httpOptions`  constant so you might try refactoring your code a bit and making use of it in your service.

So first create a class variable for httpOptions:

```
private httpOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
  headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
});
```

Then make use of it in `http.post` call by passing the additional `httpOptions` argument:

```
public addUser(newUser: User): Observable<{}> {
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/newuser', newUser, this.httpOptions);
}
```

**Possible Solution 2:** If the solution above does not work for you, then check if server expects an Authorization Bearer Token.

**Possible Solution 3:** Server might be located on another origin so check if CORS is enabled.